# Ruby - Unable to count the array values?

Tags: ruby-2.0

I have a program :

**Question** : Input a number of integer of `2 digit only` , and in the out-put it should show the all input values **BUT** loop should stop on `42` :

`example`

input

1
2
87
42
99

output

1
2
87

`my code`

```
  a = []
 5.times do |i| 
  a[i] =  Integer(gets.chomp)
 end
 a.each do |e|
   break if e == '42'
  puts e
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to change. First of all gets will give you a string together with `\n` at the end, so you need to change it to `gets.chomp` to remove it.

Now your loop should look like this:

```
a.each do |e|
  break if e == '42'
  puts e
end
```

However ruby's array has much butter function which is perfect for what you want:

```
puts a.take_while {|e| e != '42'}
```

Additional notes:

1. Note that it is operating on strings rather than numbers. You might need to validate the input at some point and convert it into integer values.
2. `5.times do|i|` - the `|i|` bit is obsolete.

Comment: I ma getting the answer same as the input.i have edited my code have a look

Comment: how to validate in input for accepting only 2 digit ?

Comment: @bindibhatt - yes, when Yyou convert input to integer you need to change '42' to 42. TO validate input you simply need to check whether you got 2 digits or not. I don't know the requirements so you need to decide what to do in such a case. You can check the format of the input with `if input =~ /\A\d{1,2}\z/`.